# I can't hear anything in Ubuntu 11.10, except for "Front Left" and "Front Right" inside settings

Tags: sound

I'm building an HTPC. It used to be a Windows 7 with no issues, but, since I want to use mdadm for my disks, I'm changing to Ubuntu with XBMC.

System specs:
`Zotac H67ITX`
`Core i3 2100T`
`8GB RAM`

I went to `System Settings`->`Sounds`->`Hardware` tab and changed the Profile to `Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output`. This is the only way I can hear something coming from the speakers on my TV. No other profile sounds anything. So this tells me the drivers for Intel sound are working.

However, I can't hear anything else from any other program, including Ubuntu sounds. So, I believe there's a misconfiguration somewhere; Ubuntu has another sound Profile as default, so I that I can't hear anything from the OS or XBMC.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Digital sound is somewhat Ubuntu. Is using a non digital connection to your TV an option? Does sound work then?

if not , i would try talking directly to the guys on the pulseaudio irc channel on irc.freenode.net